# Haskell own concat method with recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, concatenation

Im practicing recursion on Haskell and need to do concat method with own impelentation on a nested list.

I've tried

```
    myConcat :: [[a]] -> [a]
    myConcat [[]] = []
    myConcat ((x:xs)) = x : myConcat ((xs))
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

```hs
myConcat [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6]] == [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

This is the goal.

The main problem is that i dont really know how to work with nested lists.

Comment: SInce `x` is a list, you can not here use `x : ...`, unless you again want to create a list of lists.

Comment: Do you mind posting the type error for future searchability?

Answer (score 5):

Since `x` is a list here (it has type `[a]`), you can not use `x : …` here, unless you again want to create a list of lists, but then your `myConcat` would act like an `id` function for lists.

You here need to *append* `x` with the rest of the list, so you can use [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-), indeed:

```
myConcat :: [[a]] -> [a]
myConcat [] = []
myConcat (x:xs) = x ++ myConcat xs
```

Note that you forgot the base case `[]`. By writing `[[]]` you match a list with *one* element: the empty list. That is something different.

Answer (score 1):

hello you have just to replace your `x : myConcat xs` by `x ++ myConcat xs`

Comment: That's not enough. The pattern matches remain incomplete.

Comment: yes sure the case of empty List! My solution isnt complete, i just wanted to highlight the difference between `:`  and `++`